# Change default sorting on product listing in shopware 6

Tags: symfony4, shopware

I have created a new **Sorting** after this [documentation](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/extend-storefront-listing?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to) .

```xml
    <argument>a-sorting</argument>
    <argument>New Sorting</argument>
    <argument type="collection">
        <argument key="product.markAsTopseller">desc</argument>
        <argument key="product.updatedAt">desc</argument>
    </argument>
    <tag name="shopware.sales_channel.product_listing.sorting" />
</service>
```

You can select now the new Sorting in the frontend and it is working fine.
But i don't know how to set this sorting as page default. I mean the product list should be sorted initially after the page is loaded.

I solved it with **ProductListingCriteriaEvent** and **ProductListingResultEvent**

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyPlugin\Storefront\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Events\ProductListingResultEvent;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Events\ProductListingCriteriaEvent;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Sorting\FieldSorting;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class ProductSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            ProductListingCriteriaEvent::class  => 'handleRequest',
            ProductListingResultEvent::class    => 'handleResult'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductListingResultEvent $event
     */
    public function handleResult(ProductListingResultEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        /* Sorting is not selected in frontend */
        if (!$request->get('order')) {
            $event->getResult()->setSorting('a-sorting');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductListingCriteriaEvent $event
     */
    public function handleRequest(ProductListingCriteriaEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $criteria = $event->getCriteria();

        /* Sorting is not selected in frontend */
        if (!$request->get('order')) {
            $criteria->resetSorting();
            $criteria->addSorting(
                new FieldSorting('markAsTopseller', 'DESC'),
                new FieldSorting('updatedAt', 'DESC')
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I bundled part of this up in a little plugin and also added a configuration option; https://github.com/elgentos/shopware-default-sort-order

Comment: Thanks for adding your solution!

Comment: How often is it that you find the perfect solution for your problem, copy paste ready. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Excellent post, thanks @Maltisch!

I want to add a small detail: It seems like they changed the query name from 'sort' to 'order' somewhere around the 6.2 version. In my case I had to use `$request->get('sort')`.